# ssh treated my ssh private key as public key

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

my SSH seems to recognize my private key as a public key, and tries to find the private key file ending in `_sk` in the `$HOME/.ssh` directory.

I am connecting my server using `ssh root@<address>`, no extra options were set.

I noticed these lines from `ssh -vv` logs:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/reverier/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:uc+vEwEfsBy5jbVRPqTTZfS3emyPv3dKzPKxVp09R7k
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/reverier/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
```

However the file `/home/reverier/.ssh/id_ed25519` is my private key,  the `id_ed25519.pub` is the correct public key. ssh sends my private key to the server and tries to find something named `id_ed25519_sk` as private key.

here is my `/etc/ssh_config`

```
ServerAliveCountMax 5
TCPKeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 5
```

my $HOME/.ssh/config is empty.

Comment: Which distro are you using, is there anything in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/`?

Comment: I am using Arch Linux, `ssh_config.d` is not exist in my `/etc/ssh`

Comment: Also using Arch Linux, the behavior on my machine is exactly as you describe it. This answer on Security.SE sheds light onto the interpretation of the messages: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152594